# Question on Einstein Summation Convention

Tags: summation, kronecker-delta

**Question:**

Solve for $\epsilon_{ij \ell} \, \epsilon_{km \ell} \, \epsilon_{ijm} \, a_k$

**Attempted Solution:**

$$\epsilon_{ij \ell} \, \epsilon_{km \ell} \, \epsilon_{ijm} \, a_k$$

$$\Rightarrow (\delta_{ik} \, \delta_{jm} - \delta_{im} \, \delta_{jk}) \epsilon_{ijm} \, a_k$$

$$\Rightarrow \delta_{ik} \, \delta_{jm} \, \epsilon_{ijm} \, a_k - \delta_{im} \, \delta_{jk} \epsilon_{ijm} \, a_k$$

$$\Rightarrow a_i \, \delta_{jm} \, \epsilon_{ijm} - a_j \, \delta_{im} \, \epsilon_{ijm}$$

However, how should I go about solving $a_i \, \delta_{jm} \, \epsilon_{ijm} - a_j \, \delta_{im} \, \epsilon_{ijm}$?

While I know the answer is supposed to be $0$, I am not sure how I can get from the above equation to the desired answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you see terms like $\delta_{jm}$ in a tensor expression with summation, you can drop them and replace all the other $j$'s with $m$'s (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the final quantity must be zero.  The reason why is because of the terms $\delta_{jm}\epsilon_{ijm}$.  In order for $\delta_{jm} = 1$ we must have $j = m$ which forces $\epsilon_{ijj}= 0$.  Similarly, if all indices are different $\delta_{jm} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\delta_{jm}$ is symmetric but $\epsilon_{ijm}$ is $jm$-antisymmetric, their contraction is $0$. The other term vanishes for the same reason.